# After reading with BufferReader '\n' won't be accepted as a new line char, how to solve this?

Tags: java, io

I have a large text file I want to format. Say the input file is called `inputFile` and output file is called `outputFile`.

This is my code for using `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`
Here is my code

```
 public static void readAndWrite(String fileNameToRead, String fileNameToWrite) {
        try{
            BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(String.format("%s.txt", fileNameToRead)));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(String.format("%s.txt", fileNameToWrite), true));
            String currentTmp = "";
            String tmp = "";

            String test = "work \nwork";
            out.append(test);


            while((tmp = fr.readLine()) != null) {
                tmp = tmp.trim();
                if(tmp.isEmpty()) {
                    currentTmp = currentTmp.trim();
                    out.append(currentTmp);
                    out.newLine();
                    out.newLine();
                    currentTmp = "";
                } else {
                    currentTmp = currentTmp.concat(" ").concat(tmp);
                }
            }
            if(!currentTmp.equals("")) {
                out.write(currentTmp);
            }
            fr.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occoured" + e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String readFile = "inPutFile";
        String writeFile = "outPutFile";
        readAndWrite(readFile, writeFile);
    }
```

The problem is that the `test` string inside the code which have '\n' can we converted to a new line with `BufferedWriter`. But if I put the same string in the text file it would not perform the same.

In a more easy way to see is that I want my input file have this

```
work\n
work
```

and output as

```
work 
work
```

I am using mac, so the separator should be '\n'

Comment: The output you're getting is correct. You should not see the characters `\n`, only a new line being started. The `\n` inside the string literal is converted to a newline by the Java compiler, not by `BufferedWriter`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
work\n
```

if you see the "\n" in your file, it is not a new line character. It is just two characters.

The `trim()` method will not remove those characters.

Instead you might have something like:

```
if (tmp.endsWith("\n")
    tmp = tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 2);
```

> I am using mac, so the separator should be '\n'

You should use the newline character for the platform. So when writing to your file the code should be:

```
} else {
    currentTmp = currentTmp.concat(" ").concat(tmp);
    out.append( currentTmp );
    out.newLine();
}
```

The newline() method will use the appropriate new line String for the platform.

Edit:

You need to understand what an escape character is in Java. When you use:

```
String text = "test\n"
```

and write the string to a file, only 5 characters are written to the file, not 6. The "\n" is an escape sequence which will cause the ascii value for the new line character to be added to the file. This character is not displayable so you can't see it in the file.

Comment: The ``\n` is inside the Java string literal `"work \nwork"`, so it is indeed a newline.

Comment: The test string which is `work \nwork` gives the result is as expected. What my problem is that if I have \n in the inputFIle it does not perform the correct result

Comment: @MalcolmLiu, In your question you show two lines of data which is what I assume you see if you load the file into an editor. If you see the "\n" in the files, then that is NOT a end line string. That is why I stated you need to check if the line you read ends with "\n". You need to remove those two characters yourself because the BufferedReader will not remove the characters for you because is is not recognized as a newline string. See edit.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, The OP states: "But if I put the same string in the text file it would not perform the same." - so I was NOT talking about the literal string in the program, which the OP states does work. I am stating that if you see the two characters "\n" in the file, then that is NOT a newline string.

Comment: I think you are correct on the point that if in a file the BufferReader won't treat \n as one char. Rather it would treat it as two char '\' and 'n'. I think that is why when it turns to a string it still treats it as two chars. So the only solution like you said would be to replace the "\n" as one '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

After @camickr answer, I think I realized the problem. Some how if I have a text in the file like this

```
work \nwork
```

The `\n` won't be treated as a single char ('\n'), rather it has been treated as two chars. I think thats why when the `BufferWriter` writes the input string it won't treat it as a new line.

Comment: The 'somehow' has been explained. `BufferedWriter` has nothing to do with it.